# How to join list elements to create one string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join, data-structures

Can I use `"".join(list_name)` to join list elements which are string? If no, what is an alternative for joining such a list to create one string?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It's showing AttributeError

Comment: @MayurSamrutwar let us see it.

Comment: Please [edit] and add your code. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate items in a list to a single string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12453580/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

```py
l = ["Hello", "world", "!"]
print(" ".join(l))
```

Output:

```
> Hello world !
```

[For more details](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can:

```py
my_list = ["beef", "corn", "tacos"]
seperator = "\n"
list_joined = seperat
```